Find the Dini derivatives of the function
Find the Dini derivatives of the function
$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
2x \sin^2 \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + 3x \cos^2 \left(\frac{1}{x}\right), & x > 0, \\
0, & x = 0, \\
3x \sin^2 \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + 4x \cos^2 \left(\frac{1}{x}\right), & x < 0,
\end{cases} $
at ( x =0).
my attempt
\begin{align*}
&D^+ f(0) \lim sup_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} \\
&= \lim sup_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{2h \sin^2(\frac{1}{h})}{h} + \lim sup_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{3h \cos^2(\frac{1}{h})}{h} \\
&= \lim sup_{h \rightarrow 0^+} (2 \sin^2(\frac{1}{h})) + \lim sup_{h \rightarrow 0^+} (3 \cos^2(\frac{1}{h})) \\
&= \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+} (\sup(2 \sin^2(\frac{1}{h})) + \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+} (\sup(3 \cos^2(\frac{1}{h})))
\end{align*}
By the Archimedean property, there exists $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ \frac{1}{N} < \delta $ to take $ h = \frac{1}{2N\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}} < \frac{1}{N} $. This is where $ \sin^2(x) = 1 $. And $ h = \frac{1}{2N\pi + 2\pi} < \frac{1}{N} $. This is where $ \cos^2(x) = 1 $.
\begin{align*}
&D^+ f(0) = \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+} \left( \sup \left(2 \sin^2\left(\frac{1}{h}\right) \right) \right) + \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+} \left( \sup \left(3 \cos^2\left(\frac{1}{h}\right) \right) \right) \\
&= \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+} \left( \sup(2) \right)  + \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+} \left( \sup(3) \right) \\
&= 5
\end{align*}
But my question is whether the selection of
ℎ
h in the cases of sin and cos is correct because, since it is the sum of the limits, I think it is possible, but I am not sure. If someone could help me know if it's correct, I would appreciate it
